# Extract values from a property in a tuple

Tags: typescript

```js
type A = [{a: 1}, {a: 'x'}]
type TupleToUnion<T, K> = ...

TupleToUnion<A, 'a'> // expected to be `1 | 'x'`
```

How can I define `TupleToUnion`?

Answer (score 7):

To get your type, without using generics, you can use this [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```
type B = A[number]['a']
```

The following generic type should be able to emulate the above. First infer the union type of all objects in `T` (as `U`) and then index that union with `K` after asserting that it is valid and extends the available keys

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBvAhgLigRgL4Bop0sByADxNwF0AoUSKAIQViQDsBXAWwCMIAnKkhJoStetAAqHMABsIkgPYBVNgEtFbADyTCAaQB8LSVAhlgENgBMAzrH780ILWrYAzAVGVGA-FD2m5pa2UADWECCKbl5QfspIelRQWGwQAG6eKekCANx04NAAYoqKxjLySqoa2jCEIiQGQA)

```
type A = [{a: 1}, {a: 'x'}]
type TupleToUnion<T, K> = T extends Array<infer U> ? K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never : never;
type Foo = TupleToUnion<A, 'a'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I found one solution

```
type TupleToUnion<T, K> = T extends [infer R, ...infer Rest]
  ? K extends keyof R
    ? R[K] | TupleToUnion<Rest, K>
    : never
  : never;
```